# Move log file which is older than 2 days

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

I want to move log files which are older than two days to a new directory by date, like below.

**Source:**

```
1) /Test1/Server.log
2) /Test1/Server17032016.log
```

**Destination:**

```
1)/Test2/17032016/Server17032016.log
```

Create directories by date and move files there.

Comment: How you determine the new filenames?

Comment: sorry it was my mistake i m not create new file i want to just move Server17032016.log in directory
1)/Test2/17032016/

Comment: No, i want explain that'y i have put 1) and 2) but the directory is like /Test1/ or /Test2/

Comment: Maybe this is not the answer to your question but I advise reading `logrotate` tool documentation and using it as a tool to do the job instead of writing custom bash scripts.

Comment: What's supposed to happen to source file 1? It doesn't have a date suffix.

Comment: Are we supposed to hard-code `Test1` and `Test2` directory roots?

Comment: Yes it has date suffix and Test1 and Test2 is root folder

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you don't perform backups with the modified date.

Wouldn't you prefer to sort your backups on the day when they actually were backed up?

I know i would.

I'd solve the problem like this

```
#!/bin/sh

targetDirectory=$2

for file in $1; do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        if [ $(((`date +%s` - `stat -L --format %Y $file`) > (172800))) -eq 1 ]; then
                today=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
                mkdir -p "$targetDirectory"
                mkdir -p "$targetDirectory/$today"
                mv $file "$targetDirectory/$today"
                echo "$file moved to $targetDirectory/$today/$file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

(The magic number 172800, is 2 days in seconds.)

Run the script like this: `$ ./movebackup.sh "/Logfolder/*.log" Backups`

> Output

```
Server.log moved to Backups/20160319/Server.log
Server17032016.log moved to Backups/20160319/Server17032016.log
```

And run that in a cronjob at midnight each day.

Comment: It's not kind of backup I just want to be move.  So whatever date log file created I need to create directory of that date and need to be move file in that.

Answer (score 0):

OP is apparently expecting that a pathname like

```
 /Test1/Server17032016.log
```

is interpreted as if the last 8 digits in the filename are a date (day of month, month and year), and wants the directory name to be derived from that date.

A script for the given data might be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /Test1 -type f -mtime +2 | while IFS= read -r name
do
    date=$(echo "$name" | sed -e 's,^/Test1/Server,,' -e 's,\.log$,,' )
    [ -z "$date" ]          && continue
    [ "x$date" = "x$name" ] && continue
    mkdir -p /Test2/"$date"
    mv -f "$name" /Test2/"$date/"
done
```

although some refinement would be needed if the logfiles do not begin with the literal `Server`, as well as to exclude files which do not fit the pattern.